# Biblography in ConTeXt: Enumerated references like [1],[2] print errors.

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, context

In my context document I would like to set my Bibliography to be cited like this: »*what can be said at all can be said clearly [1]*«  and a bibliography that than has that number:»*[1] Wittgenstein, Tractatus* […etc.]«

For that I used this setup:

```
\setupbibtex[database={sample},sort=author]
\setuppublications[alternative=apa-de, numbering=yes, refcommand=num]
\setupcite[num][left={ [},right={]}]
```

The citation in the ConTeXt-Markup was like: `a Word\cite[Wittgenstein22]` However, it does not work: I only get [Error] where I want to see [1]. If I change `refcommand` to, lets say, `authoryears` instead of `num` I get (like expected) *[Wittgenstein (1922)]*

Does someone know how to get the numbered references working?

(using ConTeXt  ver: 2013.05.28 00:36 MKIV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `bib` file is the same directory than your document, and `context` is run twice, the only way I get an error, is with the omission of `[criterium=text]` right after `\placepublications`.

So for example:

```
\setupbibtex[database={xampl},sort=author]
\setuppublications[alternative=apa-de,numbering=yes,refcommand=num] 
\setupcite[num][left={[},right={]}]

\starttext
As \cite[article-full] already indicated, bibtex is a \LaTeX-centric program. 

See also \cite[article-minimal] 

Knuth already said it in \cite[book-full]  
\blank
{\bf References}
\placepublications[criterium=text]   
\stoptext
```

[image]
[image]